# Spaces in batch script without breaking the syntax

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way in a batch script to add multiple spaces at the beginning of each line without breaking the syntax and keeping the spaces on each line as they are as per example below?

```
   gacutil /u ^
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,^
   Version=2.28.0.725,^
   Culture=neutral,^
   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

The goal is to allow better readability not only when utilizing `gacutil.exe` but whenever writing a batch command

Comment: put `@echo` before `gacutil /u` and see the syntax result

Comment: It fails on `'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: but then you do not have caret `^` after ` gacutil /u` as per your question? Also what is the actual requirement, do you want three spaces between each line? i,e `gacutil /u 
  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,   Version=2.28.0.725...` ?

Comment: Current attempt is to be seen below, it no longer outputs a failure about syntax being misspelled, however it seems that  `@echo` prevents the command from applying as it does return neither a message about failure nor about success, it is still in the list of assemblies being registered

`   @echo gacutil /u^
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,^
   Version=2.48.0.725,^
   Culture=neutral,^
   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every executable has its own rule set for splitting up the string after the executable file name into argument values being processed further by the executable.

The windows command processor `cmd.exe` interprets a horizontal tab, a normal space, a comma, a semicolon, an equal sign and an OEM encoded no-break space (byte with hexadecimal value FF) outside a double quoted string as argument separators as it can be seen on running a batch file with name `test.cmd` with just the command line `@echo %0 $1 $2 $3 $4` from within a command prompt window with

```
test argument1,,,"argument 2";;;"argument 3 contains a comma ',' a semicolon ';' an equal sign '=' and multiple spaces"===argument4
```

resulting in the output

```
test argument1 "argument 2" "argument 3 contains a comma ',' a semicolon ';' an equal sign '=' and multiple spaces" argument4
```

`,,,` and `;;;` and `===` are interpreted as argument string separators.

The [global assembly cache tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/gacutil-exe-gac-tool) `gacutil.exe` splits up the string passed to it to argument strings different in comparison to `cmd.exe`. Commas and equal signs are not interpreted as argument separators. Only the normal space character is interpreted as argument separator, except a normal space is inside a double quoted argument string.

It is common for Windows executables that the number of argument separators between argument strings does not matter. So if there is used just one space or multiple spaces between two argument strings does not matter.

What does happen on using in a batch file following lines?

```
   gacutil /u ^
   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,^
   Version=2.28.0.725,^
   Culture=neutral,^
   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Please read first: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` reads a batch file line by line with replacing carriage return + line-feed by just a line-feed on reading a line.

The caret character `^` at end of a line is interpreted by `cmd.exe` as an escape character for the newline character line-feed resulting in concatenating the next line with the current line which is repeated until either reaching end of the batch file or finding a line-feed not escaped with `^`. There are no characters removed during the concatenation of lines in a batch file.

The result for the lines above in the batch file with three leading normal spaces on each line is:

```
gacutil /u    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,   Version=2.28.0.725,   Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

The three leading spaces left to `gacutil` at beginning of the command line are removed by `cmd.exe`, but all other spaces are kept because of `cmd.exe` cannot know if they are important for the program/script to run next or not. So there are four spaces after `/u` and three spaces between the other strings specified on separate lines in the batch file.

`gacutil.exe` interprets the command line now as list of following arguments:

1. `/u`
2. `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,`
3. `Version=2.28.0.725,`
4. `Culture=neutral,`
5. `PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

The result is an error message because of `gacutil.exe` must be run in this case with just two arguments:

1. The option `/u` to instruct the global assembly cache tool to uninstall an assembly from the global assembly cache
2. and the assembly name `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,Version=2.28.0.725,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`.

So the indenting spaces used in the batch file between the individual parts of the assembly name argument string not removed by `cmd.exe` makes the command line invalid for `gacutil.exe`.

For that reason it is not possible in this case to define the assembly name argument string on multiple lines with indenting spaces because of how `cmd.exe` concatenates the lines with keeping the spaces and how `gacutil.exe` splits up the string passed to it from `cmd.exe` into arguments.

A different executable could do the string splitting to a list of argument values different and for that reason writing the arguments of the executable on multiple lines in a batch file with indent spaces could work for this executable.

But the following syntax can be used in a batch file for this use case:

```
   gacutil /u ^
   ^"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,^
   Version=2.28.0.725,^
   Culture=neutral,^
   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35^"
```

The global assembly cache tool has no problems with one or more spaces after a comma in assembly name as long as the entire assembly name argument string is enclosed in double quotes. For that reason there is a `"` at beginning and one more `"` at the end of the assembly name string. But the two double quotes must be escaped with `^` for the Windows command processor as otherwise `cmd.exe` would interpret the caret character `^` at end of each line as literal character and not as an escape character.

The command line spread over multiple lines must be interpreted by `cmd.exe` as a line with no argument string in double quotes to get each `^` interpreted as escape character while the assembly name is in real enclosed in double quotes on running finally `gacutil.exe` with the command line:

```
gacutil /u    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,   Version=2.28.0.725,   Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
```

Yes, that is strange.